# React-Native Array of objects comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects. I am trying to compare each object to see if it is the same my `id` variable. . How would do I do that This is what I have done so Far.

When I console log the array I get this:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

This is coming from my Redux Reducer so this is what I am doing:

```
const Content = (props) => {
    const id = props.navigation.getParam('Id')
    const favorite = useSelector(state =>
            state.favs.favourites.some(fav => fav.id === id)
        );
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: can you add the data? (may be use JSON.stringify(arr) for console.log. you are using `some` means as long as one id found in array, it will return true. is that intended? if you need to check "each object to have same id", then use `every` method.

Comment: I did `JSON.stringify(arr)` and I am still getting false when it is supposed to render true as the Id's are the same so I think the way I am obtaining the data is incorrect